# Word Realms won't start from the Menu anymore on Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux, linux-mint, launcher, application-launch

Installed [Word Realms](http://wordrealms.com) on Linux Mint 16 per its included instructions.  It worked fine launching from the OS menu, for a time.  Now when I try to launch it, same way as always, nothing happens: no window comes up, the processor fan doesn't even spool up, no running process left, nothing.  I'm not sure if a system update broke it, or what, but I didn't change anything intentionally.  If I go into caja and find the binary and double-click it, it works fine.  How can I get it to work from the menu again?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround: If I right-click its Menu entry, go Edit Properties, then change "Application" to "Application in Terminal", it now launches fine again (albeit with an extra terminal window floating around that you can't close without closing the game.)  The window says `(Word Realms:2321): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large` but I'm not sure what that means or if that is the cause of the game not launching.  The game window appears just after that message appears in the terminal window.